# ssh executed from Windows PowerShell displays GUI open file dialogue window

Tags: windows, ssh, powershell

I attempted to ssh from Windows 10 to Ubuntu Linux 20.04 and the *"How do you want to open this file?"* window appears. I have no idea why or what this has to do with an `ssh`. Documentation shows info being displayed in PowerShell. NOT this open file dialogue box.

Command used on Windows 10 box

```
PS C:\Users\Steven Sparks> ssh steven@192.168.1.38
```

192.168.1.38 is my Nvidia ORIN Ubuntu 20.04 box. No issue with pinging either direction. Also, PuTTY and WinSCP connects to the ORIN box without issue. So, there is NO connection issues. I just stumbled across this when I attempted using `ssh` from Windows.

Windows:

```
PS C:\Users\Steven Sparks> winver
Version 22H2 (OS Build 19045.3803)
```

Linux:

```
    steven@ubuntu:~$ hostnamectl
       Static hostname: ubuntu
             Icon name: computer
            Machine ID: dbfef1aa0b064bcf9d30ec3ad0886edb
               Boot ID: 0dd920986e79467887c51ae52a10e240
      Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
                Kernel: Linux 5.10.120-tegra
          Architecture: arm64

    steven@ubuntu:~$  sudo service ssh status
    ● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
         Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; vendor preset: e>
         Active: active (running) since Wed 2024-01-10 14:45:05 PST; 1 day 4h ago

    steven@ubuntu:~$ sudo ufw allow ssh
    Skipping adding existing rule
    Skipping adding existing rule (v6)
```

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-Command ssh
CommandType     Name    Version    Source
-----------     ----    -------    ------
Application     ssh     0.0.0.0    C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Get-Command ssh` should return `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`:

```
PS C:\Users\my> Get-Command ssh

CommandType    Name       Version    Source
-----------    ----       -------    ------
Application    ssh.exe    8.1.0.1    C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe
```

Yours does not. I guess you have some conflicting file (or folder?) `ssh` in `C:\WINDOWS\system32\ssh` that shadows the `C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe`. Check it. And delete it, if it is there by mistake.

Or run `ssh.exe` using its full name, instead of just `ssh` (as the shadowing file seems to be named only `ssh`).

Comment: Manually deleting system files from `%WinDir%` is pointless because they will be restored upon running `sfc /scannow` since `sfc` would detect that as corruption and restore the files/directories from the Component Store [`%WinDir%\WinSxS`].